# android studio progress bar within for loop not displaying output

Tags: java, android, for-loop, user-interface, progress-bar

I have an issue with a progress bar within a for loop. I want to set the process of a task to the output of this bar.

```
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private int mprogress_value = 0;
```

The following code snippet is my for loop I've checked it though the debugger and the lines to set the progress bar do run but it does not update the UI. I have also tried setting the progress bar in the oncreate manually once it does set the value.

```
int data_size = ac.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < ac.getCount(); i++) {
        if((i >= data_size) && (p10_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(100);
        p10_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.9) && (p9_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(90);
        p9_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.8) && (p8_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(80);
        p8_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.7) && (p7_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(70);
        p7_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.6) && (p6_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(60);
        p6_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.5) && (p5_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(50);
        p5_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.4) && (p4_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(40);
        p4_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.3) && (p3_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(30);
        p3_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.2) && (p2_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(20);
        p2_set = true;}
        else if((i >= data_size*.1) && (p1_set == false)){
        mProgressBar.setProgress(10);
        p1_set = true;}
        ac.moveToNext();
    }
```

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/local_data_progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progress="0"/>
```

Why does it not update the UI and how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you initialize the Progress bar with its ID ?

Comment: Yeah I did add the ID